# PHP PDO Fetch not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can successfully select an object, but I cannot fetch all rows from the database using the following code, can anyone see any obvious errors?

```
    $sql2 = "SELECT ID, Latitude, Longitude, Name FROM Countries";
    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $countryID = $row->ID;
        echo $countryName= $row->Name;
        echo $longitude2 = $row->Longitude;
        echo $latitude2 = $row->Latitude;
    }
```

Comment: You should use those arrays as: `$row['key']`, not `$row->key`.

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` fetches an assoc array, which you use as an object, use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` or change `$row->ID` to `$row['ID']`. There's also no params in your query, you needn't `prepare` it if it really is a hard-coded query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) tells PDO to return the result as an associative array. SO you can fetch array not object

```
 while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $countryID = $row['ID'];
        echo $countryName= $row['Name'];
         //Rest of the code

    }
```

Comment: Ahhh arrays - thanks, will accept the answer when I can

Comment: You are welcome @Frog82 !! enjoy . Who has given downvote at least dare  to give reason.

Comment: @Saty: I suspect the -1 is because, when taken literally, your answer might be seen as incorrect (_"So you can fetch array not object"_ could be taken to mean `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` doesn't exist). Another reason why one might down-vote is you failed to address other (less obvious) issues like the pointless `PDO::prepare` call and the redundant assignments (`echo $countryID = $row['ID'];` vs `echo $row['ID'];`). I'm just guessing here, though, seeing as I didn't vote down, but I, too, dislike down-votes without a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that `PDO::FETCH` constants are on purpose. And if you want to use object notation, you have to specify `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` instead of `...ASSOC`.

Anyway, `PDO::FETCH_LAZY` should be most preferred way, as it will let you use ANY notation:

```
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) {
    echo $row->ID;    // all
    echo $row['ID'];  // three
    echo $row[0];     // works
}
```

with even less memory overhead than any other method. With no memory overhead at all, to be exact.

Comment: Not sure about the _"less memory overhead"_ part of your answer. Have you checked the implementation, and compared the overhead? If so, how? The `PDORow` instance it returns [has quite a few handlers](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4a2e40bb861bc3cf5fb6863e57486ed60316e97c/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L2664)... Or are you referring to memory overhead caused by using all possible notations, in which case I agree, but the handlers do have some (negligible/micro-optimizable) overhead