# PDO error while fetching records

Tags: php

```
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'myusername', 'mypassword' );
$query = $db->query( 'SELECT a.title, a.descrption, a.icon, b.title, b.descrption, b.images
FROM explorefeatures AS a, blog AS b WHERE a.id = b.id' );
while ( $row = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) )
{
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($row);
    echo $row->title;
    echo  $row->icon;
    echo $row->images;
    echo $row->descrption;
}
```

> Trying to get property of non-object in ...

I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `FETCH_ASSOC` returns an *associative array*, not an object...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO Fetch not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402802/php-pdo-fetch-not-working)

Comment: Try to access your results as an array not as an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FETCH_ASSOC` means: "hey, PDO, *fetch* me an *associative* array".
an associative array is **not** an object. you have to access it like an array:

```
while ( $row = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) )
{
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['icon'];
    echo $row['images'];
    echo $row['description'];
}
```

alternatively, you *can* fetch as object. you just have to tell PDO to do so.

```
while ( $row = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) )
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->icon;
    echo $row->images;
    echo $row->description;
}
```

see also: [PDOStatement::fetch()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Thanks it works  I just change PDO::FETCH_OBJ to FETCH_ASSOC  for some testing purpose and forget to change it Thanks again

Comment: if a post answers your question, the customary response is to upvote & accept it ;)